# How to Reload Partition Data into ORC

Tags: hive, hadoop-yarn, azure-hdinsight

Is there any Best practices for loading data into ORC with Partition . If I load 120 GB of data into ORC Partition table. And Partition is on 2 columns. If want reload data for particular partition how to do reloading activity. How to Delete Partition, is it Alter Table Drop partition(Partition Value). Even after deleting the partition, I still see ORC partition file in Hive/WareHouse Folder. How to cleanup unsed partition File. If I want to load only single Partition data into delete partition, how to perform and what is best way.

Is ORC with Partition with Bucket can give better performance than ORC with Partition and then ORC (No Partition)

Answer (score 0):

Dropping a table or a partition only removes the metadata information but does not necessarily delete the data for an external table. You should instead use TRUNCATE to delete the data in an external table or partition. Read more [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL).